# WSL: How to remove the entry for uninstalled distribution from File Explorer?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I had installed WSL Ubuntu and deleted. But, as you see below, "Ubuntu" is still on the pane, and I cannot find any way to remove it. Clicking it does not work, because Ubuntu has been already uninstalled.

[image]

Comment: How did you delete the distribution? Did you do `wsl --unregister Ubuntu`?

Comment: The unregister command removed it; thanks. I had installed it from the MS Store, and I probably uninstalled it by deleting the app. And it is Win 11.

Comment: Good to hear you got it unregistered.  See this question - [Remove WSL2 files after distro uninstall on Windows 11](https://superuser.com/questions/1746522/remove-wsl2-files-after-distro-uninstall-on-windows-11) for details on why that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of all ones registered in your system.

```
wsl -l -v
```

Then just remove it via:

```
wsl --unregister <distro name>
```